# Is there a way to tag a facebook page from SLComposeViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7

There's little more to add. Is there a way to tag a facebook page from SLComposeViewController from iOS 6 or 7?

I tried the obvious, adding the @FacebookPage but it appeared as plain text in the Facebook Wall. But that same thing did work in Twitter, which didn't surprise me.

Is there a way to tell Facebook that Im trying to tag a Facebook page?

Thanks.

Comment: Nope, gave up on this..